# common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexFieldToken

Tags: apex, unit-test, sobject, schema, describesobject

We have using SmartFactory class from long time. But, recently we are facing issues while running smartfactory unit class. [Smart Factory Git hub repo](https://github.com/mbotos/SmartFactory-for-Force.com). When I try to see the logs I've found out this. I didn't find any documentation related to apexfieldtoken runtime exception. Please guide me to handle this issue.

Log:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted
> picklist field: Evaluating: [Stage__c]

```
08:56:35.0 (69520456)|METHOD_EXIT|[67]|01p61000009D2vF|SmartFactory.fieldMapFor(String)
08:56:35.0 (69623875)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:876
08:56:35.0 (69733852)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[67]|Bytes:876
08:56:35.0 (69881301)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[67]|Bytes:5
08:56:35.0 (69920758)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[67]|field|Schema.SObjectField|true|false
08:56:35.0 (70115387)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[67]|field|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexFieldToken@7d88e5b"|0x7d88e5b
08:56:35.0 (70133953)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[67]
08:56:35.0 (70138536)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[68]
08:56:35.0 (70147389)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[68]|Bytes:21
08:56:35.0 (70268784)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[68]|Bytes:2
08:56:35.0 (70289190)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[68]|Bytes:23
08:56:35.0 (70312567)|USER_DEBUG|[68]|DEBUG|@@@@datainfieldmap@@@Id
08:56:35.0 (70323939)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[69]
08:56:35.0 (70347309)|METHOD_ENTRY|[69]|01p61000009D2vF|SmartFactory.setFieldValue(SObject, Schema.SObjectField, Boolean, Integer)
08:56:35.0 (70381388)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[141]|obj|SObject|true|false
08:56:35.0 (70412551)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[141]|obj|{}|0x5e0658d2
08:56:35.0 (70422413)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[141]|field|Schema.SObjectField|true|false
08:56:35.0 (70555224)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[141]|field|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexFieldToken@7d88e5b"|0x7d88e5b
08:56:35.0 (70585170)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[141]|cascade|Boolean|false|false
08:56:35.0 (70601214)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[141]|cascade|false
08:56:35.0 (70611332)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[141]|counter|Integer|false|false
08:56:35.0 (70627462)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[141]|counter|1
```

Code:

```
Schema.sObjectType token = GlobalDescribe.get(objectType);
        if (token == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedObjectTypeException('Unsupported ObjectType ' + objectType);
        }

        SObject obj = token.newSObject();       
        List<Schema.SObjectField> allFields =fieldMapFor(objectType).values();
        for (Schema.SObjectField field : allFields) {
            System.debug('@@@@datainfieldmap@@@'+field);
            setFieldValue(obj, field, cascade, counter);
        }
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = field.getDescribe();

        if (fieldDescribe.isCreateable() && 
            (
                isIncludedField(obj, fieldDescribe) || 
                (
                    (
                        (!fieldDescribe.isNillable() || 
                        FillAllFields) || 
                        (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Reference && cascade) // always fill references with cascade
                    ) && 
                    !isExcludedField(fieldDescribe) &&
                    !isExcludedField(obj, fieldDescribe) &&
                    !isPersonAccountField(fieldDescribe)
                )
             )
            ) {

            if (fieldDescribe.getName().endsWith('Country')) {
                obj.put(field, DefaultCountry);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getName().endsWith('State')) {
                obj.put(field, DefaultState);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getName().endsWith('CountryCode')) {
                obj.put(field, DefaultCountryCode);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getName().endsWith('StateCode')) {
                obj.put(field, DefaultStateCode);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.base64) {
                obj.put(field, blob.valueOf(counter.format()));
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Boolean) {
                obj.put(field, false);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Combobox) {
                obj.put(field, counter.format());
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Currency) {
                obj.put(field, counter);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Date) {
                obj.put(field, Date.today());
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.DateTime) {
                obj.put(field, DateTime.now());
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Double) {
                obj.put(field, counter);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Email) {
                obj.put(field, 'test' + counter.format() + '@test.com');
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.EncryptedString) {
                obj.put(field, 's');
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Id) {
                //System.debug('Id field ' + fieldDescribe.getName());
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Integer) {
                obj.put(field, counter);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.MultiPicklist) {
                obj.put(field, getDefaultPicklistValue(obj, fieldDescribe));
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Percent) {
                obj.put(field, counter);
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Phone) {
                obj.put(field, '123-456-7890');
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Picklist) {
                obj.put(field, getDefaultPicklistValue(obj, fieldDescribe));
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getName() == 'CommunityNickname' && fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.String) { 
                obj.put(field, 'test'+ string.valueof(math.roundtolong(math.random()*1000000)) ); 
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getName() == 'UserName' && fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.String) { 
                obj.put(field, 'test'+ string.valueof(Userinfo.getOrganizationId())+ string.valueof(math.roundtolong(math.random()*1000000))+ string.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace('-','').replace(':','').replace(' ','')+'@test.com'); // was a@a.com
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.String) {
                obj.put(field, counter.format()); 
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Reference) {
                String referenceObjectType = fieldDescribe.getReferenceTo()[0].getDescribe().getName();

                if (referenceObjectType == 'RecordType') {
                    setRecordType(obj);
                }else if (referenceObjectType == 'Profile') { 
                    obj.put(field,userProfile.Id);
                } else if (cascade && referenceObjectType != obj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() &&
                            referenceObjectType !='BusinessHours') {
                    // TODO avoid infinite loop for same-type references
                    System.debug('Creating reference to ' + referenceObjectType + ' for field ' + obj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() + '.' + fieldDescribe.getName());
                    SObject reference = createSObject(referenceObjectType);
                    System.debug('Inserting ' + reference);
                    insert reference;
                    obj.put(field, reference.Id);
                }
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.TextArea) {
                obj.put(field, counter.format()); 
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Time) {
                obj.put(field, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)); 
            } else if (fieldDescribe.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.URL) {
                obj.put(field, 'http://test' + counter + '.com'); 
            } else {
                System.debug('Unhandled field type ' + fieldDescribe.getType());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, the error is complaining about a particular picklist, so that's where you should naturally start. This feels like an org issue instead of a code issue. You should look at your `Stage__c` picklist and verify that `"Evaluating"` is an active option and that it's available under your default record type in the org that you're experiencing this issue in.

Comment: @DerekF it worked but i dont need this value in my default custom record type then how can i handle this issue.

Comment: Reading the link that you provided, by using `ExcludedFields`?

Comment: Works like charm. Could you post your response as answer, will close this one. Thanks @DerekF for jumping on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is complaining about the `Stage__c` picklist field. You have it configured as a restricted picklist (and maybe required as well?), so the value you specify needs to be in the active list of picklist values.

A brief look at that data factory you're using suggests that it just fills things in based on default values (with some field types having that information being part of the field metadata itself).

To be able to use a picklist value, it not only needs to be active in the picklist metadata itself, but it also needs to be marked as available for use on a per-recordtype basis (in the record type's metadata). The exception to that is if your object has no custom recordtypes defined and is just using the "master" recordtype.

Unfortunately, that code you're using has no provisions to change/override default values or pass in an sobject with some fields already populated. The documentation only shows setting/changing field values after you get the constructed instance back.

If you don't care about that particular field, the code you're using does have a provision to exclude fields by putting a key/value pair into the `ExcludedFields` map (key = sobject api name, value = field api name)